# Hyperlink to open a script

Tags: windows-7, command-line, hyperlink

We have several Windows desktops used by different individuals with several `.bat` files stored in a common location (say E: drive) in every machine. I am in the process of setting up a web-page in our intranet site with hyperlinks to run each batch file.

As machine names change from PC to PC I am not able to use a hyperlink something like this:

```
\\chethan-PC\e$\scripts\one.bat
```

I tried using `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in place of PC name but it did not help. Hence I am interested to know if there is any way to achieve this objective.

One alternative I could think of, is to have scripts in a server. But this is not feasible in our case as users will be making modifications on local copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for an address:

```
file:///E:/scripts/one.bat
```